# Yii2 Custom Standalone Validation

Tags: php, validation, yii2

OK, I believe I will have many custom validations so I have decided to create a standalone validation class as per [Yii Standalone Validation Doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#standalone-validators).

This particular validator is to make sure either company_name or name is filled in, so Either Required.

I have created the class in app\components\validators\BothRequired.php

```
<?php
namespace app\components\validators;
use Yii;
use yii\validators\Validator;

class BothRequired extends Validator
{
    public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute)
    {
       //validation code here
    }
}
```

Here is the model

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['company_name', BothRequired::className(), 'skipOnEmpty' => false, ],
    ];
}
```

However this validation requires some params to be passed to the validation in this example I need to send the second attribute that is needed to be checked against. I cannot seem to work out how to do this, if I create the validation rule in the model itself then I can pass `$params` but i dont know how to pass to this standalone class.

Also on a further note, what would be a lot better for me is if I could have a class with all my custom validators in it rather than a file per validator.

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: My guess would be that if you had attributes on the validator class then you could fill them by sending `'attribute' => <value>` in the rule (like the 'skipOnEmpty' one, which I bet is an attribute of `Validator`. That seems like the kind of thing Yii would do.

Comment: I have tried passing various variables, 'params', 'other'. First it complains that it is not a property, then if i set it as a public property in the class nothing else happens

Comment: OK thanks, you pushed me in the right direction, I will add the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK,

With the help of @gandaliter I have found the answer

Validator class

```
namespace app\components\validators;
use Yii;
use yii\validators\Validator;

class BothRequired extends Validator
{
    public $other;
    public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute)
    {
        if (empty($model->$attribute) && empty($model->{$this->other})) {
            $this->addError($model, $attribute, 'Either '.$attribute.' or '.$this->other.' is required!');
            $this->addError($model, $this->other, 'Either '.$attribute.' or '.$this->other.' is required!');
        }
    }
}
```

Model rule

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['company_name', BothRequired::className(), 'other'=>'contact_name', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, ],
    ];
}
```

As you can see you have to declare the property you are going to send over in this case it is `$other` and then use it in the code as `$this->other`

I can then validate both items.

I hope this clears it up

Liam

P.S. On the other note I mentioned.... How would be able to put all validators in one class?